# Imgur API - Get non-album images

Tags: api, imgur

(Copied from a post I made on the imgur community forums on Nov 10 https://community.imgur.com/t/imgur-api-get-non-album-images/61788 . I have reposted it here because it was suggested by the Imgur Help team.)

I'm trying to retrieve a list of all images in my account that are not in an album. This doesn't appear to be supported in the public API?

I can call `https://api.imgur.com/3/account/{{username}}/images`, but it lists all images, including those in albums. I can't seem to find any way to set it to only show me images that are not already in an album.

The non-public API used by imgur.com itself seems to call: `https://imgur.com/ajax/images?sort=0&order=1&album=1&page=1&perPage=60`. The album=1 parameter appears to make it so the results are only those images that are not albums. I tried seeing if doing something similar would work with the public api calls, but I couldn't find a way to make it work.

Is there support for this feature that I'm just not seeing? Or is this a limitation of the public API.

In theory, I could just fetch the imageHashes of all the images on the accounts, fetch all the albums, and then figure out which imageHashes are not in an album. But that would be horribly inefficient.

If this feature is missing from the public API, would you consider adding it?